# return query results from FB.api call with custom function

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this code:

```
getThirdPartyID : function () {                     
    return FB.api("/me?fields=third_party_id", function (userData) { 
        console.debug("Your Facebook ThirdPartyId is: " + userData["third_party_id"]);
        return userData["third_party_id"];
    });
},
```

But it returns empty. Whats the problem with this code? How can I access it with the same idea? tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FB.api` is function which doing asynchronous request to Facebook API and return nothing. You can only get results within `callback`. You should leverage different approach to implement this:

```
var someObj = {
  getThirdPartyID : function (thirdPartyIDCallback) {
    return FB.api("/me?fields=third_party_id", function (userData) { 
      console.debug("Your Facebook ThirdPartyId is: " + userData["third_party_id"]);
      thirdPartyIDCallback(userData["third_party_id"]);
    });
  }
}

var handleThirdPartyID = function(thirdPartyID){
  // do something with thirdPartyID
  alert(thirdPartyID);
}
someObj.getThirdPartyID(handleThirdPartyID);
```

Answer (score 1):

FB.api work async. This means that your function returns before FB.api callback function returns.

You should set the return value of FB.api to a variable or call other function inside of FB.api callback function.

```
function GetUserData(val){
 alert(val);
}
getThirdPartyID : function () {                     
    FB.api("/me?fields=third_party_id", function (userData) { 
        console.debug("Your Facebook ThirdPartyId is: " + userData["third_party_id"]);
        GetUserData(userData["third_party_id"]);
    });


};
```

Comment: thanks probably this answer is the same as the second one. it helped me!